# Create a range column but always list all the options

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with following columns:
Year, Month, SalesRange, NumOfBuyers, AvgSale. So a sample row would look like:
2015  09 - '1-149.99' - 3 - 89.50
meaning in sep of 2015 there are 3 buyers that placed an order in the value between 1-149.99 and the avg of these 3 buyers' orders is 89.00

I am creating a range column based on the sale column and using the case statement.

For example:

```
`
CASE
WHEN Sales <= 149.999 THEN '1-149.999'
WHEN Sales > 149.999 AND Sales <= 349.999 THEN '150 - 349.999'
WHEN Sales > 349.999 AND Sales <= 749.999 THEN '350 - 749.999'
WHEN Sales > 749.999 AND Sales <= 999999.999 THEN '750 - 999999.999'
END SalesRange
`
```

This works great except in the cases where there are no items with, let's say price of $100, in which case the range '1-149.999' never gets displayed.
What I need is that all the ranges are always displayed.
So, from the previous example if there were no buyers whose orders were between 1-149.99 this category would never be displayed and I need it to be displayed with NumOfBuyers = 0 and Sales say equal to NULL.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Then you need a table with all the ranges as the foundation of your query, then left join to your sales data.

Comment: If you need more detailed assistance we need a more detailed question. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Thanks Sean! Was hoping there was a way to do it within that case statement but I guess not. I did it by creating a temp table with hardcoded ranges and then right joining it to the main query. Thanks again!